# twillio integeration with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, twilio

Need help with integrating Twillio in a rails app made for making appointments. I am trying to integrate twilio to send appointment reminders.
I have two models User & Appointment.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid, :name, 
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
end


class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base      
    attr_accessible :discription, :appointment_time, :reserve_time, :reserve_date
    belongs_to :usermodel
end
```

and now there is the appointment reminder from Twillio which i want to integerate:   https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

The documentation works with controller only and it is ambiguous, Do i need to create a new model and have relationship with User or Appointment model? 
Really need some help, please

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the Twillio client in an initializer and setting it to a global variable:

`config/initializers/twillio`

```
require 'twillio-ruby'

# put your own credentials here
account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth_token = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

$twillio = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
```

Now you can interact with the twillio client using `$twillio` wherever you need to. For example if you what to send a text message when an appointment is created you could do something like this:

```
class AppointmentsController
  ...
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
    if @appointment.save
      appointment_message = "Your appointment has been booked for #{@appointment.date}"
      $twillio.account.messages.create(:from => '+14159341234', 
                                       :to => @appointment.user.phone_number,
                                       :body => 'Your appointment has been booked')
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to schedule an appointment reminder text message consider using something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to queue a worker that will perform the action at the time you want. Using sidekiq your create appointment action would then look something like this:

```
class AppointmentsController
  ...
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
    if @appointment.save
      TextReminderWorker.perform_in(@appointment.datetime - 30.minutes, @appointment.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your `TextReminderWorker` you would send the text.

Comment: Thanks very much steven, I want the text to be sent exactly half hour before the appointment is scheduled ex: send text at 3:00pm when appointment time is 4:00pm.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger that action at a specific date and time in rails.

Comment: Look into using something like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs) to schedule a background job for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We put together a tutorial for appointment reminders using Ruby that could be helpful here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/appointment-reminders/ruby/rails

Here's the code block in this tutorial where we're sending the reminder:

```
  # Notify our appointment attendee X minutes before the appointment time
  def reminder
    @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    time_str = ((self.time).localtime).strftime("%I:%M%p on %b. %d, %Y")
    reminder = "Hi #{self.name}. Just a reminder that you have an appointment coming up at #{time_str}."
    message = @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => @twilio_number,
      :to => self.phone_number,
      :body => reminder,
    )
    puts message.to
  end
```

For scheduling the reminder, we're using [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with the ActiveRecord adapter.